# aplicativos Delphi 7 no windows 8

Tags: windows, delphi-7, indy-9

Eu instalei o Delphi 7 no meu Windows 7, porém sabemos que por padrão o Delphi 7 vem com Indy 9. Para mim tudo bem, pois eu utilizo apenas o `idhttp.post` e o `get` via http.

As dúvidas seriam:

Esse componente `idhttp` que vem no Delphi 7 é nativo e roda nos Windows sem precisar de dll?

Os app feito em Delphi 7 com esse `idhttp`, Indy 9 padrão Delphi 7, mesmo que a atual seja Indy 10 e Delphi 10, ele roda sem problemas no windows 8?

Se puderem me ajudar respondendo já testo.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho aplicativos feitos em Delphi utilizando o Indy 10, usando os componentes para envio de e-mail, não tenho problemas nesse caso nem com o win8 nem win7.

É simples substituir o Indy 9 pelo 10 da uma olhada nesse artigo:

http://fabriciodev.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/instalando-indy-10-no-delphi-7.html

Porém alguns *recursos* rodam de maneira diferente no windows7/8 para o xp, então quando for buildar um aplicativo, tenha certeza de testar ele nos 2 cenários, caso seja necessário implantar ele dessa maneira.

Comment: sim obrigado a informação, mais tipo a minha pergunta foi se os app delphi7 indy 9 roda no win8 tranquilo sem dll...

Comment: Bom, não utilizei essa idhttp, então não sei se ele precisa de dll, porem utilizando o IDSMTP, tanto do indy9 quanto do 10, independente da versão do windows e necessário adicionar essas duas dlls *libeay32.dll e ssleay32.dll*

@JuniorVieira Não é possível fazer o upgrade do 9 para o 10 em todo caso? Quando eu utilizava o 9 tinha diversos problemas com o envio de email em geral.

Comment: Pesquisando pelo forum da embarcadero, encontrei esse post https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=659456

Onde eles dizem que além da dll, ainda seria necessário acertar o Timeout, para que possar rodar no Win8.

Answer (score 1):

Sim. O Indy 9 que vem no D7 é totalmente compatível com as novas versões do windows 7, 8 e 10 e roda normalmente neles.

Não. Não precisa de nenhuma DLL a ser distribuída junto com o executável. Somente precisará de DLLs se você usar HTTPS, do contrário não.

Apesar de ser possível instalar o Indy 10 no D7, não é necessário, o Indy 9 funciona bem para o que você quer (idhttp)

Answer (score 1):

Qualquer versão do Indy a partir da 9 irá rodar sem necessidade de distribuição de DLL em qualquer versão do windows existente até hoje. O que difere a versão do componente Indy é apenas os recursos que o mesmo oferece.